# When should I use Django media files instead of static files for a very large number of images that are not user-uploaded files?

Tags: python, django

My Django web app serves up millions of images (not including the regular images such as site logos that are normally served up as static assets and are version controlled). These images will only ever be placed on the server by an admin, and they will never be stored in version control. Using Django's MEDIA_URL/MEDIA_ROOT seems the obvious way to store and serve these images, however the Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/) say that these file access methods are for 'those [files] uploaded by a user', which is not the case for my large collection of images. Please can someone advise me what the best practice is to handle these type of images: MEDIA_URL/MEDIA_ROOT or STATIC_URL/STATIC_ROOT. Many thanks.

I have tried and tested both methods (MEDIA_URL/MEDIA_ROOT or STATIC_URL/STATIC_ROOT) of serving these images and both work, however I'm sure one method is preferable to the other. One point of concern going down the STATIC_URL route would be how long it takes collectstatic to find and move millions of images. There is an expectation that new batches of images (up to 100k per batch) will be added to the collection of images over time; I'm unsure how well collectstatic will scale up to this task as so far I've only tested it with a handful of images (less than 50).

Comment: I'd say get used to them being uploaded, so media files storage. No admin wants to dive into the files of a production web server every time they want an image changed. Have a way for them to be uploaded if you can! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.